# Hyper-V Enhanced session doesn't work when using

Tags: xubuntu, display-resolution, hyper-v

I'm trying to configure an Ubuntu VM in Hyper-V. It's pretty easy and fast for creating Ubuntu VMs but I can't manage to make enhanced session work with them. I've installed version 20.04LTS, also tried with 20.10, and I've followed the guides to manually enable it, basically:

set-VM -VMName "VMName" -EnhancedSessionTransportType HvSocket from powershell with admin privilegies after executing install.sh [in](https://github.com/microsoft/linux-vm-tools/pull/113)  .... Some other guides talk about manually modifying xdrp.ini which I also did... but no luck.

According to Hyper-V console, it's enabled the check to allow using Enhanced Sessions for the VMs with compatible guest OSs... so my question is: Is it Ubuntu compatible with this Hyper-V feature? If so, why is not working out of the box? Which is the trick? No one of the solutions that I mentioned above seem to work for me... I've a Windows 10 Enterprise fully up-to-date 20H2.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

443 views and no answers.  While the OP is probably on to bigger and better things finding these questions unanswered is unfortunate when you have the problem in the present.

I have gone through this merry-go-round.  For some reason it's temperamental.  You cannot get it to work, at least in my experience, with the quick create in Hyper-V that downloads the 20.04 LTS version.  You have to create the virtual using the "new" selection and follow this guide: https://www.nakivo.com/blog/install-ubuntu-20-04-on-hyper-v-with-enhanced-session/

Just make sure you use the ISO names ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
Then it will work.

Comment: Hello. What about later when that link and guide are gone? This means you have not given any answer. Please include an vital parts in the answer you post.